# How to encrypt password parameters in HTTP Authorization Manager - JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I have a password parameter inside of http authorisation manager But I would like to encrypt it first rather than just putting a plain password.
What would be a solution?

Comment: Hello, any update on answer? if ok you should accept it and upvote so that it’s helpful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to avoid having a plain password in jmx file, then you can pass it on command line using:

> -Jpassword=mypassword

And in plan use function [__P](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P):

> ${__P(password)}

Otherwise, you can use a variable and use in a [setup thread group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) that will contain a [JSR223Preprocessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) that will decrypt the password and create a property using:

> props.put("password", decryptedPassword)

You can then just use the password using :

> ${__P(password)}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, JMeter's [JMX test scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) are basically [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) files so everyone will be able to guess the password by opening the file in the text editor.

If you put decryption logic somewhere in the test plan then everyone will be able to call the function and decrypt the password.

I would recommend going for [__env() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#envsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) (it's a part of Custom JMeter Functions bundle, can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)) so the password will be read from your operating system [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), this way is more secure and [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) friendly.